# Conjugate prior for a Gamma distribution

Tags: bayesian

I need to update the failure rate (given as deterministic) based on new rate of failure about the same system (it is a deterministic one too). I read about conjugate priors and Gamma distribution as a conjugate for the Poisson process.

Also, I can equate the mean value of Gamma dist. ($\beta/\alpha$) to the new rate (as a mean value) but I do not have any other information such as standard deviation, Coefficient of Variation, 90th percentile value,...etc. Is there a magic way to manipulate that and find parameters for the prior Gamma hence I get the posterior which Gamma too?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you please edit the text and add a bit more context?

Comment: ... and maybe a better topic?

Comment: I attempted to make it a better title; feel free to change it to something more appropriate

Comment: What parameterization are you using for your Gamma?

Comment: @CharlieParker - you are asking a different question than the OP; please don't modify the OP's question and bounty it!  You should ask your own question.

Comment: @CharlieParker - a quick search for "Gamma distribution conjugate prior" turns up https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262570/conjugate-priors-for-gamma-distribution-of-unknown-alpha-and-beta

Answer (score 16):

I believe M. Tibbit's answer refers to the general case of a gamma with unknown shape and scale. If the shape α is known and the sampling distribution for x is gamma(α, β) and the prior distribution on β is gamma(α0, β0), the posterior distribution for β is gamma(α0 + nα, β0 + Σxi). See this [diagram](http://www.johndcook.com/conjugate_prior_diagram.html) and the references at the bottom.

Comment: Couldn't you just simulate the posterior Gamma distribution from the full conditionals defined by the conjugate priors of the Gamma alpha and beta respectively? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

A Gamma distribution is not a conjugate prior for a Gamma distribution.  There is a conjugate prior for the Gamma distribution developed by Miller (1980) whose details you can find on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) and also in the pdf linked in footnote 6.  Checkout section 3.2 on page 25 of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.157.5540), there is a prior with four parameters: p, q, r, & s