Generating Samples from the Unnormalized Gamma Conjugate Prior
Wikipedia lists the following as an unnormalized conjugate prior of the gamma distribution in the case where both parameters $\alpha,\beta$ are unknown:
$$
 \frac{p^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta q}}{\Gamma(\alpha)^r \beta^{-\alpha s}}
$$
Looking at the paper by Miller, it seems I can even take $s=r=n$, although it is not critical to the rest of my question.
Given valid hyperparameters $p>0,r=s>0,q>0$ (such that $p^{1/r} <q/r$ as per the paper), I would like to generate many (say a million) random samples $(\alpha_i,\beta_i)_{i=1}^N$ from this distribution. Ideally, I would like the samples to be exact and independent, but I couldn't get any of the methods listed on Wikipedia to work.
I believe I did manage to code a correct implementation of Metropolis-Hastings for the problem below, but this has the issue that the samples are correlated.
I would greatly appreciate help in coding an exact and efficient sampling algorithm with independent samples. In rejection sampling for example, that should involve some smart bound on the unnormalized PDF. Any such method will do. Thanks.
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the unnormalized PDF
def unnormalized_pdf(alpha, beta, n, p, s):
    return (beta**(alpha*n)) * (p**(alpha-1)) * np.exp(-s*beta) / (sp.gamma(alpha)**n)

# Metropolis-Hastings algorithm
def metropolis_hastings(n_samples, n, p, s, alpha_init=1.0, beta_init=10.0, proposal_std=0.5):
    samples = np.zeros((n_samples, 2))
    alpha_current = alpha_init
    beta_current = beta_init
    
    for i in range(n_samples):
        alpha_proposal = np.abs(np.random.normal(alpha_current, proposal_std))
        beta_proposal = np.abs(np.random.normal(beta_current, proposal_std))
        
        acceptance_ratio = (unnormalized_pdf(alpha_proposal, beta_proposal, n, p, s) / 
                            unnormalized_pdf(alpha_current, beta_current, n, p, s))
        
        if np.random.rand() < acceptance_ratio:
            alpha_current = alpha_proposal
            beta_current = beta_proposal
            
        samples[i, :] = [alpha_current, beta_current]
    
    return samples

# Initialize parameters
alpha = 1.0
beta = 10.0
n = 10

# Draw samples from gamma distribution
gamma_samples = np.random.gamma(alpha, 1.0/beta, n)

# Set s and p
s = np.sum(gamma_samples)
p = np.prod(gamma_samples)

# Number of samples for MCMC
n_samples = 1000000

# Run the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm
samples = metropolis_hastings(n_samples, n, p, s)

# Plotting the samples
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(samples[:, 0], samples[:, 1], s=0.1, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Alpha')
plt.ylabel('Beta')
plt.title('Samples of (Alpha, Beta) Pairs')
plt.show()


Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/227035/updating-gamma-conjugate-prior (only MCMC solution given). Presumably the Miller paper should be https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00401706.1980.10486102 (the current link is broken)
