# Posterior (conjugate) prior of two parameter Gamma likelihood

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

This question is related to a previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262570/conjugate-priors-for-gamma-distribution-of-unknown-alpha-and-beta) on this site. Assume some data is generated from Gamma distribution $p(x\mid\alpha,\beta) \sim \operatorname{Gamma} (\alpha,\beta)$, and both parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unknown. Wikepedia presents that the conjugate prior of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Continuous_distributions)) when these two parameters are known is $p(\alpha,\beta)\propto\frac{p^{\alpha - 1} \exp(\beta q)}{\Gamma(\alpha)^r \beta^{-\alpha s}}$ where $p, q, r, s$ are hyperparameters.

My questions are:

1. Is there any known formula to compute the partition function of
   $p(\alpha,\beta)$?
2. How to interpret the meaning of the four hyperparameters $p,q,r,s$?
3. Is it possible to derive the posterior distribution for a single
   parameter, e.g., $p(\beta\mid X,\alpha)$?

Comment: 1. I do not think so - 2. Not likely. - 3. $\beta$ given $\alpha$ is from a Gamma, a priori and a posteriori.